# How to keep dirty data sorted in a Lightswitch Grid

Tags: queue, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an entity that has an "Order" column.

I have a grid onscreen bound to a collection of said entities.

Entity items should move up and down the grid, simply by changing the value of "Order" as the query that populates the collection is sorted by "Order".

The logic of this works perfectly, however I cannot get the grid to sort it's rows programmatically, neither does it do it automatically save for when the data initially loads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to write code in `TestQuery_PreprocessQuery` like:

```
partial void TestQuery_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<Label> query)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(c => c.Order);
}
```

Also there has been some considerations about calculated fields, relational fields and resorting. you can take a look at this [Lightswitch grid sort problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/48af3c60-01f8-4727-8da8-6a21e6c057b8/)